# Error compiling kernel 5.15.2

Tags: kernel, compiling

I'm trying to compile kernel 5.15.2 and running into errors. How to I fix them?

#### Background

I'm using a new laptop (Asus ROG M16) and for some reasons my wifi and bluetooth don't work on either kernel 5.13 or 5.14. As I update to kernel 5.15, bluetooth and wifi work but then the suspend feature becomes broken (the laptop does not suspend, but instead logs out and gets blank screen, fans run on full speed, and I have to do a hard reset). I'm trying to update to kernel 5.15.2 to see whether the issue is fixed.

#### Error

```
At main.c:160:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:76
sign-file: : No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modinst:83: /lib/modules/5.15.2/kernel/arch/x86/crypto/aegis128-aesni.ko] Error 1
make[1]: *** Deleting file '/lib/modules/5.15.2/kernel/arch/x86/crypto/aegis128-aesni.ko'
make: *** [Makefile:1794: modules_install] Error 2
```

#### Step to reproduce

- Download the kernel from the [kernel archives](https://www.kernel.org/)
- Extract the kernel
- Run the following commands on terminal

  ```
  $ make menuconfig  
  $ sed -ri '/CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS/s/=.+/=""/g' .config  
  $ sed -ri '/CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_KEY/s/=.+/=""/g' .config
  $ sed -ri '/CONFIG_SYSTEM_REVOCATION_KEYS/s/=.+/=""/g' .config
  $ make  
  $ make modules  
  $ sudo make modules_install
  ```

#### Other info

- Ubuntu 21.10
- Current kernel 5.15.1-051501-generic

Comment: @Nmath I have added some background and the link to the kernel

Comment: Kernels from kernel.org are not tested and expected to work with Ubuntu.  This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).  Your *actual* problems have to do with wireless and suspend. I suggest that you ask about that.

Comment: I am not familiar with your method of compiling so might be wrong. You also have to disable "SYSTEM_REVOCATION_KEYS" these days. While mainline kernels do not have to work with Ubuntu, typically they do work fine.

Comment: @DougSmythies I also tried to disable `CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_KEY` and `CONFIG_SYSTEM_REVOCATION_KEYS` but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I only compile kernels on Slackware, not Ubuntu, but I am not familiar with what you are doing with the sed + keys command lines?

Comment: @andrew.46 basically I set the `CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS` and others to empty, avoiding error requiring certificate

Comment: You can download the .deb packages of the kernels from https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.15.2/ Then you will not have to compile them.